# Run Cronjob every night between 3-6 o clock but only once

Tags: cron, anacron

I want to run a cronjob daily at a specific time range but only once in that period.
How is that possible?

I see a possibility in anacrhon but don't know how to set up such scenario.

Comment: Why do you need a range? You can specify a specific time within that range like 4:30.

Comment: Because I don't want backups done while I work and can't ensure that the PC is turn on at a particular time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place you cronjob in `/etc/cron.daily/` and it will automatically run in that timeframe.

---

#### Edit:

Sorry, I was referencing an old Debian installation where `anacron` wasn't installed by default. In that case `/etc/cron.daily/` was executed by `/etc/crontab` on 6:25. But newer Debian installations (and so does Ubuntu) install `anacron` by default and so `/etc/cron.daily/` will be executed by `/etc/anacrontab` five minutes after `anacron` was started or every new day.

---

To achieve your schedule (from the comments) you can set up a cronjob that will e.g. every 10 min between 3-6 start either `anacron` that will take care that the backup job only run once or you can write a custom controll script.

#### 1. Alternative: anacron

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/anacron_spool
echo "1 0 backup.daily /path/to/backup.sh" > ~/.config/anacrontab
(crontab -l; echo "*/10 3-6 * * * /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t $HOME/.config/anacrontab -S $HOME/.local/share/anacron_spool") | crontab -
```

This will make anacron to serialize (`-s`) run all jobs defined in `~/.config/anacrontab`. Because by default only root has write permission to write to `/var/spool/anacron/` where the timestamps are stored we use a custom spool-dir (`-S`). If all jobs are done for today anacron will exit.

#### 2. Alternative: custom controll script

Open an editor (e.g. `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/run_once_a_day.sh`) and paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SPOOL="$HOME/.local/share/run_once_spool/"
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) <job-identifier> <command>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $SPOOL ]; then
    mkdir $SPOOL
fi

if [ -e ${SPOOL}${1} ]; then
    last_run=$(cat ${SPOOL}${1})
else
    last_run=0
fi

today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
if [ $last_run != $today ]; then
    $2
    echo $today > ${SPOOL}${1}
fi
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. Make it executeable and add a cronjob that will start it periodicaly with:

```
sudo chmod 755 !$
(crontab -l; echo "*/10 3-6 * * * /usr/local/bin/run_once_a_day.sh backup.daily /path/to/backup.sh") | crontab -
```

Comment: Please add information where to set-up the timeframe. Just placing the file there won't do I guess. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A cron job will run every time **only once** on a given schedule/time. So, if you set a cron job at which time do you wish between 3 and 6, this will run only once at a specified time. Only once, and never more than once!

See more explanations and some examples at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: And what if this particular time has passed while the pc was off? Will crontab run it on startup?

Comment: @MikePretzlaw Well, all the interval between 3 and 6 can pass while the PC is off.

Comment: If so, then the time window is gone - doesn't matter. Will `* 3-6 * * * foo.sh` run once between 3 and 6 o'lock ?

Comment: @MikePretzlaw No, cron doesn't understand intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest work-around is to have a wrapper script being called every N minutes during the interval, but it starts by checking for the existence of a "locker" file it creates upon execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f /dev/shm/cron-once-script-lock ]] && exit 0
touch /dev/shm/cron-once-script-lock

actualcronjob.sh # or whatever non-script command it may be

# end of wrapper script
```

And the cron line would be like:

```
*/10 3-6 * * * /wherever/the/script/is/wrapper-script.sh
```

Or perhaps

```
*/10 3-6 * * * bash /wherever/the/script/is/wrapper-script.sh
```

The only caveat is that cron runs under a restricted "environment" and you may need to export environment variables and this sort of stuff, but that's another subject altogether.