# Shell calling shell(s) and passing env variable(s) or not

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I want to launch/run `/usr/bin/FreeFileSync` (FFS) from my crontab at most once a day, whenever the external backup target volume is mounted.

For that, I used @Germar's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334596/run-cronjob-every-night-between-3-6-o-clock-but-only-once/334602#334602echo%20$?): i.e. a spooling-script that does a couple of tidy-up chores before calling a small backup-script as second argument to the spooling-script's basename.  The called backup-script (the child process) in turn performs a check and calls FFS (the grand child process).

Because FFS opens its main GUI upon launch, I think I need to declare `stdout` for instance as:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1; export DISPLAY   # I have two screens
```

My question is whether I should declare my DISPLAY *environment variable* within the child script or within the parent spooling-script that calls it ?

Does @muru's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493746/pass-variables-to-script-which-called-script) applies in the case ? I.e. if I include the DISPLAY statement within the child script, do I need to source it inside the parent script, knowing I am dealing with an *environment variable*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options :

1. You can use :

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0.1
   ```

in the parent script. As we are using `export` the variable will be inherited by all child processes.

2. You can use :

   ```
   DISPLAY=:0.1
   ```

in the child shell (if it calls further subshells use `export` in front). In this case as the child script is calling `FFS` just putting the `DISPLAY` in the child script will suffice.

Comment: +1 Excellent. So it is indeed different from passing variables with assigned values from sub-shells to parent shells. Thanks a lot @heemayl. I needed that little tap on the shoulder to put me on the right tracks on this.

Comment: @Cbhihe glad i could help :)